# Networkx cmap: Problem associated with color of network nodes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, networkx

I am trying to plot the nodes network with blue color (cmap=plt.cm.Blues) based on the weight as defined in my_value. The code is producing a network with correct weights but only with black color.

Please help me. Thanks in anticipation.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'from': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '4', '4'], 'to': ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']})
carac = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'], 'myvalue': ['0.1', '0.5', '0.1', '0.5', '0.1', '0.1', '0.2']})
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df1, 'from', 'to', create_using=nx.Graph())
G.nodes()
carac = carac.set_index('ID')
carac = carac.reindex(G.nodes())

nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, node_color=carac['myvalue'], node_size=1500, edge_color='b')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the required node coloring, the parameters `node_color`, `cmap`, `vmin`, and `vmax` are involved. Colormap (cmap) provides color-mapping based on the defined value ranges of vmin and vmax.

Here is the relevant code (import statements omitted):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'from': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '4', '4'], 'to': ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']})
carac = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'], 'myvalue': ['0.1', '0.5', '0.1', '0.5', '0.1', '0.1', '0.2']})

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df1, 'from', 'to', create_using=nx.Graph())

carac = carac.set_index('ID')
carac = carac.reindex(G.nodes())

nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, \
                 node_color=[np.float(t) for t in carac.myvalue.values], \
                 node_size=1500, edge_color='b', \
                 font_size=12, font_color='r', font_weight='bold', \
                 vmax=float(max(carac['myvalue'])), \
                 vmin=float(min(carac['myvalue'])))

plt.show()
```

The output plot will be similar to this:

[image]

EDIT 1

This is an update version of the code above. It also plots a colorbar as a legend for the nodes' coloring.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib as mpl

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'from': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '4', '4'], 'to': ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']})
carac = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'], 'myvalue': ['0.1', '0.5', '0.1', '0.5', '0.1', '0.1', '0.2']})

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df1, 'from', 'to', create_using=nx.Graph())

carac = carac.set_index('ID')
carac = carac.reindex(G.nodes())

# some parameters for colorbar
cmap = plt.cm.Blues
vmin = float(min(carac['myvalue']))
vmax = float(max(carac['myvalue']))
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)

# plot network
nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, \
                 node_color=[np.float(t) for t in carac.myvalue.values], \
                 node_size=1500, edge_color='b', \
                 font_size=12, font_color='r', font_weight='bold', \
                 vmax=vmax, \
                 vmin=vmin)

# create colorbar
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax))
sm._A = []
cb1 = plt.colorbar(sm)
cb1.set_label('Some Units')

# hide x,y ticks
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])

#set background color
plt.gca().set_facecolor('beige') 

plt.show()
```

The sample plot:

[image]

Comment: Hello again @swatchai,

I also need to add colorbar in my figure. I am using the following command as:

nc = nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True, cmap=plt.cm.cool, node_color=[np.float(t) for t in carac.myvalue.values], node_size=1500, edge_color='b', font_size=12, font_color='b', font_weight='bold', vmax=float(max(carac['myvalue'])), vmin=float(min(carac['myvalue'])))

plt.colorbar(nc)

But somehow it doesn't work. Can you please help?

Comment: @Anks I think it should be asked as a new question, more people will see and help. You will get more point hopefully.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the suggestion.